# Select not bind with model

Tags: angularjs, combobox, angular-ngmodel

I am having problems with a select and yours model. In this example, usaStates is an object array stored into the root scope.

```
<label>State:</label>
<select name="state" ng-model="selectedState" ng-options="state.name for state in usaStates" required ng-change="getCities()">
    <option>Select a state</option>
</select>
```

So, in my controller i have:

```
$scope.selectedState = null;
$scope.getCities = function()
{
   console.log($scope.selectedState);
   var stateCode = $scope.selectedState.id;
   MainService.getCities(stateCode)
   .then(function(httpData){
      $scope.cities = httpData.data;
   })
   .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
   });
};
```

When a state is selected, the getCities function is fired, but `$scope.selectedState` is null. I have this code in another views and works fine. Why here not ? Any ideas ?

**UPDATE**
My state source is:

```
[{id: "AL", name: "Alabama"}, {id: "AK", name: "Alaska"}, {id: "AZ", name: "Arizona"},…]
```

Comment: how does `usaStates` object look like ?

Comment: also, can you share a  jsfiddle/plnkr ?

Comment: can you try changing the ng-model to an object,`ng-model=selectedState.Name`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the model value does not get the knowledge and the ng-change gets fired earlier.

You could pass it by as a parameter.

```
<select name="state" ng-model="selectedState" ng-options="state.name for state in usaStates" required ng-change="getCities(selectedState)">
    <option>Select a state</option>
</select>
```

In the controller.

```
$scope.selectedState = null;
$scope.getCities = function(selectedState)
{
   console.log(selectedState);
   var stateCode = selectedState.id;
   MainService.getCities(stateCode)
   .then(function(httpData){
      $scope.cities = httpData.data;
   })
   .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
   });
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result is the same.-

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the `selectedState` to `getCities(selectedState)` function.

**E.g.**

**HTML**

```
<select name="state"
        ng-model="selectedState" 
        ng-options="state.name for state in usaStates" 
        ng-change="getCities(selectedState)"
        required="required">
    <option>Select a state</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.selectedState = null;
$scope.getCities = function(selectedState) {
    $scope.selectedState = selectedState;
    console.log($scope.selectedState);
    var stateCode = $scope.selectedState.id;
    MainService.getCities(stateCode)
            .then(function(httpData) {
                $scope.cities = httpData.data;
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
};
```

Hope it helps.